# Couldn't find Menucard without an ID. Nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, nested

When I want to go into my Menucards products index (http://localhost:3000/menucards/1/products)  I get the following error:
Couldn't find Menucard without an ID.
In this page I'd like to show all the products in the current menucard.

This is my productscontroller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :load_menucard

layout 'admin'

def index
    @products = @menucard.product.all
end

def new
    @menucard = Menucard.find(params[:id])
    @product = @menucard.product.new
    redirect_to @product
end

def create
    @menucard = Menucard.find(params[:id])
    @product = @menucard.product.new(params[:product])
    if @product.save
        redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    delete_product
end

def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if  @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        #redirect_to @product
        redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

private

 def load_menucard
    @menucard = Menucard.find(params[:id])
 end

end
```

menucardscontroller:

```
class MenucardsController < ApplicationController

layout 'admin'

def new
    @menucard = Menucard.new
end

def update
    @menucard = Menucard.find(params[:id])
    if  @menucard.update_attributes(params[:menucard])
        #redirect_to @menucard
        redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def edit
    @menucard = Menucard.find(params[:id])
end

def index
    @menucards = Menucard.all
end

def create
    @menucard = Menucard.new(params[:menucard])
    if @menucard.save
        #redirect_to @menucard
        redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
    @menucard = Menucard.find(params[:id])
    if menucard.destroy
        redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    end
end
end
```

Product view index:

```
<h1>Alle producten</h1>
<%= link_to("Product toevoegen", {:action => 'new' }, :class => 'btn btn-green') %>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Naam</th>
        <th scope="col">Beschrijving</th>
        <th scope="col">Prijs</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @products.each do |p|  %>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" title=""><%= p.name %><%= link_to("- bewerken", { :action => 'edit', :id => p.id}, :class => 'show-edit') %></a></td>
            <td><%= p.discription %></td>
            <td><%= p.price %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the problem is in your 'load_menucard' definition. As it is nested resource, it should be params[:menucard_id] not params[:id].

Replace

```
@menucard = Menucard.find(params[:id])
```

by

```
@menucard = Menucard.find(params[:menucard_id])
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Thnx for the reply. After changing it to menucard_id I get the following error: undefined method `product' for #<Menucard:0x007f89048ad6f0>

Comment: I found out what caused my next error. In the definition 'index' I used '@menucard.product.all' product needed to be plural. Thnx for your help!